# Umbraco - How to import Dictionary between Umbraco instance

Tags: umbraco

We are working with Umbraco 4.5. We have different culture set in the site. for that we use Dictionary object.

We completed our development locally now we need to deploy our changes on our Production Server. We want our Local Umbraco Dictionary to be imported to Production Server with some automated process. As we have more than 1000 Keys in Umbraco  Dictionary.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Script the SQL changes in the cmsDictionary and cmsLanguageText tables (they are related)
2. Create a package (right click on Packages in the Developer section > Create). In there you will be able to choose the dictionary items you want to include. With a 1000 keys, you don't really want to do that though.

Also, the upcoming version of Courier for Umbraco should be able to alleviate trouble with content migration (any type of content).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this Umbraco Package: [Dictionary Dashboard](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/dictionary-dashboard)

It's **easy to install, you can specify in which Section of the Backend it can be seen** (by default this "Dictionary" Tab is available under "Content". (Umbraco official "Dictionary" is under "Settings" and I don't like that: if the customer wants access there he will need a user with admin rights, which I don't like (can mess with other things)...).

You export your dictionary as XML, you can easily edit it (if needed), you can import it in another umbraco installation (where you must install this package of course).

It's really one of my favorite packages.

**It works from Umbraco 4.7.x till 6.x** (with umbraco 7 I don't know, try...)